# ngview display only the home page

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a simple views with angualrjs + ngRoute.

Why it doesn't work for me??? 
It shows only the home page when I press in the contact nothing change and it stay at home page why?
my router 
`

```
angular.module('appRoute', ['ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'views/pages/home.html'
  })
  .when('/contact' , {
    templateUrl : 'views/pages/contact.html'
  });
});`
```

app.js

```
' angular.module('UserApp', ['appRoute']);'
```

the index.html
    '

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/contact">contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#findjob">Find Job</a></li>

          </ul>
</div>

      <div ng-view>    
      </div>
</div>'
```

Comment: as far as I can see your archer doesn't match the route in angular /contact not #/contact

Comment: In my JSFiddle is all working https://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/1zkbxk8b/1/

Comment: @gherkin should still work. however, is the app initialized? does it say anything in the console?

Comment: @gherkin I use angularjs so # is not matter if I added or not

Comment: @A.Q You have no error in console logs ?

Comment: @HorstJahns Console doesn't say anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the matter 
by changing router code to:
angular.module("appRoutes", ['ngRoute'])

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

   $routeProvider.when('/',{
      templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/home.html'
   })
.when('/contact' , {
   templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/contact.html'
})
.otherwise({
   redirectTo: '/'
});
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
 enabled: true, 
 requireBase: false
  });
});
```

In index.html just add in

```
 <head>
<base href="/">﻿
```

and remove # from

```
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a  href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
```